# Create http request with WebWorker

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to use nativescript web worker and i'm having a problem . 
i want to make the http request in the webWorker.ts using http angular service
i need to import the http angular servie to the worker.ts and use it there

I've tried to send the http service as a parameter to the worker.ts but its do not works because its Initializing the service

I was hoping that the code will look something like that
worker.ts

```
require("globals");
(<any>global).onmessage = (msg: any) => {
       (make the httpRequest..... ).subscribe(response=>{
          (<any>global).postMessage(response);
        })

}
```

did you have any idea how can i do it ?